# Can Office 365 sharepoint can be access using Sharepoint SOAP based API

Tags: office365, sharepoint-online

We have android application in which we are using SOAP based API to use sharepoint.

With Office 365 sharepoint online in market, we want to use this so that we can add more features in android app.

Since Office 365 authentication uses azure for authentication purpose (ADAL can be used for this).

We are trying to access Office 365 sharepoint using existing SOAP based API with ADAL (by using access token). But we are unable to do so.

Is this combination correct, if not what can be done.

Answer (score 0):

No SOAP API but there is a full REST API